# How to efficently flatten JSON structure returned in elasticsearch_dsl queries?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, flatten, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I'm using elasticsearch_dsl to make make queries for and searches of an elasticsearch DB.

One of the fields I'm querying is an address, which as a structure like so:

```
address.first_line
address.second_line
address.city
adress.code
```

The returned documents hold this in JSON structures, such that the address is held in a dict with a field for each sub-field of address.

I would like to put this into a (pandas) dataframe, such that there is one column per sub-field of the address.

Directly putting address into the dataframe gives me a column of address dicts, and iterating the rows to manually unpack (`json.normalize()`) each address dict takes a long time (4 days, ~200,000 rows).

From the docs I can't figure out how to get elasticsearch_dsl to return flattened results. Is there a faster way of doing this?

Comment: Have you tried converting the `Series` (column) to a list and passing directly to the `DataFrame` constructor..? ie something like `pd.DataFrame(df['address].tolist())` ...

Comment: Can you give a short example of the JSON from elasticsearch?

Comment: Hi @chrisa I found that didn't produce a dataframe I could concatenate onto the original, but I've found a similar solution that I've put below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Searching for a way to solve this problem, I've come across my own answer and found it lacking, so will update with a better way**

Specifically: `pd.json_normalize(df['json_column'])`

In context: `pd.concat([df, pd.json_normalize(df['json_column'])], axis=1)`

Then drop the original column if required.

**Original answer from last year that does the same thing much more slowly**

`df.column_of_dicts.apply(pd.Series)` returns a DataFrame with those dicts flattened.

`pd.concat(df,new_df)` gets the new columns onto the old dataframe.

Then delete the original column_of_dicts.

`pd.concat([df, df.address.apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)` is the actual code I used.